# Sporadic 401 authentication errors when trying to access google APIs

Tags: php, oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

We are running a PHP application that talks to google spreadsheet API a bit. This works just fine, using google-apiclient package with a bit of glue code above. OAuth tokens are issued, refreshing works, all just fine. Hundereds of calls a day.

But sometimes, calls fail with

```
 {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Just the same call worekd minutes ago, and afterwards again.

I first suspected an exprired access_token, but this time the token was just 5 minutes since last refresh. Following calls, with the same token work fine.
I also double checked that the request was really carrying a token.
Any idea how to debug that further?

The above error message was raised at 08:00 UTC, using the following credentials. print_r of the google api client library array:

```
Array
(
    [access_token] => ya29[...]
    [expires_in] => 3599
    [scope] => https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
    [token_type] => Bearer
    [created] => 1692777302
    [refresh_token] => 1//09[...]
)
```

some more insights from the log:

```
[2023-08-23T07:55:02.933710+00:00] main.INFO: Got a Google API refresh, token Array
    [access_token] => ya29.a0AfB[...]
[2023-08-23T07:56:38.247386+00:00] main.INFO: Initializing Google API with working token Array
    [access_token] => ya29.a0AfB[...]
[2023-08-23T07:57:02.004642+00:00] main.INFO: Initializing Google API with working token Array
    [access_token] => ya29.a0AfB[...]
[2023-08-23T08:00:02.541705+00:00] main.INFO: Initializing Google API with working token Array
    [access_token] => ya29.a0AfB[...]
[2023-08-23T08:05:01.881548+00:00] main.INFO: Initializing Google API with working token Array
    [access_token] => ya29.a0AfB[...]
```

The second last call raised the error at 08:00. The one at 08:05 worked ok again.
Created_at 1692777302 is Wednesday, 23. August 2023 07:55:02, which aligns with the log.
This is supposed to expire 1692777302+3599=1692780901 = Wednesday, 23. August 2023 08:55:01

The google code checks with a grace period of 30, see (striped some unimportant bits):

```
 public function isAccessTokenExpired() {
    $created = $this->token['created'];
    return ($created + ($this->token['expires_in'] - 30)) < time();
}
(from vendor/google/apiclient/src/Client.php)
```

I tried raising that to 300s with no improvement.

Comment: access tokens expire after an hour please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Hey Linda, I cannot reproduce, as this is sporadic every few days. Therefore no usefull code example around. According to API, they expire after one day.

Comment: Can I see the documentation that states a google access token expires after a day?   If i cant see how you are running this Its hard to help show me your code how you are requesting authorization,  how you are refreshing authorization,   how you are storing the refresh token.   how you are making a request.   Without seeing your code its hard to help.

Comment: Agreed, we could do with a [mre] of the issue, and I am also doubtful about your assertion regarding the token expiry time. https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/token-types#at-lifetime certainly doesn't reflect that.

Comment: The above error message was raised at 08:00 UTC, using the following credentials. print_r of the google api client library array:
`
#29 {main}Google API Token usedArray
(
    [access_token] => ya29[....]
    [expires_in] => 3599
    [scope] => https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
    [token_type] => Bearer
    [created] => 1692777302
    [refresh_token] => 1//09[....]
)
`

Comment: Thanks but please [edit] your post when you have important info to share, so that a) it's not hidden in the comments out of context and b) it can be formatted and presented properly.

Comment: `[expires_in] => 3599`... this is 3599 seconds, which is 59.98333 minutes (effectively, 1 hour). So if it was 2 hours since you generated the token, it's not surprising that it was rejected when you tried to use it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the obvious. Calling myself stupid now! Obivously there should be code catching that (which it usually does), I'll check why it didnÄt request a new one.
I had my head confused to 3600s = 1 day, which is obiviously wrong.

Comment: OK, updated that. 2hours was wrong. Token was refreshed at 07:55 UTC, error raised at 08:00 UTC. updating above